# NoClassDefFoundError in SpringBoot jar, depends on machine

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jar, noclassdeffounderror

- I build and pack a *Spring Boot* app into a *jar*
- Send the *jar* to be deployed to other people
- They run it, and at runtime they got `NoClassDefFoundError for org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/tree/DeleteStatement` at some delete action through *jpa* repository method `deleteInBatch()`
- I get back this *jar* from them and run it in my local machine, on same db - no errors
- OK, I pack for them another *jar*, in same damn git branch, send it
- All good on their side now

How's that possible?
(Before I have no problem)

Comment: How do you build the jar file?

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple versions of Hibernate packaged in the same jar? Different classloaders will load the versions in different orders, so you can run into cases where the class is not found.

Comment: @DánielKis - `mvn clean package`

Comment: @LucasP - i don't think so, i check the jar - there only one hibernate lib (`DeleteStatement.class` included), and `hibernate-core` added by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, i didn't specify multiple versions of hibernate in `pom.xml`

Comment: What version of `hibernate-core` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` are you using?

Comment: @LucasP `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is `1.3.8 RELEASE`, `hibernate-core` is `4.3.11 FINAL`